# ASP.NET MVC 3 update URL when returning a view.

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

In my controller action I return a view and I also need to update the url in the browser
so if the request url is test.site.testsite.com I want to change it to search.site.testsite.com how can I do this.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

So I'm not positive about sub-domains but [HttpContext.RewritePath()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpcontext.rewritepath.aspx) allows you to modify the URL. This should give you a start.

Comment: I'll give it a try. Will this work using VS 2010 built server? Or should I deploy on test box with IIS 7?

Comment: That didn't work. Lets say the url is search.site.testsite.com the pages loads. Then the user types in abcd.site.testsite.com since this new url will result in a redirect to search.site.testsite.com and since we are already on that page using HttpContext.RewritePath doesn't change the url.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve the above by following,

1. In IIS host two WebSites (test.site.testsite.com and search.site.testsite.com) both pointing to same physical/virtual directory.
2. In the Controller action , you can use a filter attribute which will redirect all search request to search.site.com.